# RStudio does not see packages after update to R 3.4

Tags: r, path

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and after update of R to 3.4.1 version it does not see my packages even though they have also been updated:

```
> library(dplyr)
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’
```

Packages are there:

```
$ ls ~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/ | grep plyr
dplyr
plyr
```

My `.libPaths`:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"       "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

**Setting `.libPaths` to desired path does the thing just for one session.** I'd like it to be permanent.

I also tried to set the variables `R_LIBS`, `R_LIBS_SITE` and `R_LIBS_USER` to desired path as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387660/how-to-change-libpaths-permanently-in-r?answertab=votes#tab-top) but it worked only in the console (didn't work in RStudio).

Comment: The problems are almost the same but mine considers Linux not Windows and none of the answers solves my problem.

Comment: That is fair enough - Maybe you could have found some inspiration for solving it. Mark your own answer as accepted so others can see the solution :)

Comment: I can't accept it for another 2 days.

Comment: Looking at this post this looks like planned behaviour and the 'canonical' solution is to make `usr/local/lib/R/` writable for all users who will use R. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861967/r-3-4-1-single-candle-personal-library-path-error-unable-to-create-na), [this thread](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866768) and [steps for making this folder writable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44903158/3022126)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution:
In the file `/usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron` there is a configuration of R.

In lines 43-45 there is:

```
# edd Jun 2017  Comment-out R_LIBS_USER
#R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'}
##R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/Library/R/3.4/library'}
```

I have uncommented `R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'}`, restarted RStudio and now it works.

**EDIT:** Looking at the comments, it seems like a planned behaviour. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861967/r-3-4-1-single-candle-personal-library-path-error-unable-to-create-na/44903158#44903158) is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 16.04. Call terminal R and try to install one any package in the terminal. Then use rstudio.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows, maybe my solution works for you aswell. The default for R-Studio seems to be, that it looks for the packages in a folder that has the same name as the most recent R version you have installed.

So check in the Library Settings for R-Studio, (e. g. Tools -> Install packages -> Path beneath the search bar) it should say some path ending in `~/3.4.1 [Default]`, whereas the packages currently lie in `~/3.4`.

**What I did:**

Copy/move the content from `~/3.4` to `~/3.4.1`.

This is obviously not the nicest way, since that means moving the packages with every R update, but it worked for me.

Edit: formatting.

Comment: Going into ` Tools -> Install packages` I have: `Would you like to create a personal library 'null' to install packages into?`.