# Local libraries path removed from R path after minor upgrade

Tags: r, linux

I have a lot of packages installed in `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/`. Today, I opened R, and attempted to run some code, and I found that packages were not being recognised:

> Error in library("some_package"): there is no package called ‘some_package’

I looked at the paths, and I got this:

```
.libPaths() 
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

which explains why packages are not longer recognised. Now, I know how to solve this (add local path to R paths, e.g. modifying `/etc/R/Renviron`).

Notice that I updated R via `sudo apt-get update...`. However, **the update was minor** (from 3.4 to 3.4.1) (so this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401904/painless-way-to-install-a-new-version-of-r)). [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25024196/) is the command line output of the update/upgrade. It seems the issue might have been related to the update of `/etc/R/Renviron`, as the line `Replacing config file /etc/R/Renviron with new version` indicates.

My packages source is

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

My question is, **why did this change happen?** Does every **minor** change in R restores the paths to default? Is it somewhere explained in some documentation? I can't find a warning about it [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html) or elsewhere.

Comment: I don't know why it happened, but if you start R with `sudo R` then you should be able to install the packages.

Comment: @DiscoSuperfly I have the packages already installed. The solution is to run `.libPaths("~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/")` in R. I want to know why a minor update removed my local path from R. I see why this happens in major updates (the path actually changes from say 3.3 to 3.4), but within 3.4, they are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to 3.4.1's new(?) default behaviour of making the same library of R packages available to *all* users on your Linux system. See here for a neat solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44903158/4115816

(The thread also describes some other options.)

Comment: Thanks. This is actually a dupe then. Flagged accordingly.